# What makes this query untranslatable in EF Core 3.x?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a simple model and query:

```
public class Item
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Boolean Complete { get; set; }
}

List<Item> lstIncompleteItems = await context.Items.Where(currentItem => currentItem.Complete == false).ToListAsync();
```

This results in the "could not be translated" exception. I've read about the breaking changes when moving from EF Core 2.x to 3.x but I think something has failed to register in my brain about it. Just trying to understand exactly how to write my queries in translatable format.

What is it that makes the above query untranslatable, while the following works perfectly fine?

```
List<Item> lstItems = await context.Items.Where(currentItem => currentItem.Name.Contains("something")).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Which imports did you use for the `Where` part?

Comment: @MaartenDev You know what, your question, immediately helped me answer my own. In my actual code, complete is "internal" and not "public" for other reasons and that seems to be the source of my misunderstanding. When public, this works as expected.

Comment: Great! I added it as answer so others can find it @ThatGuy

Answer (score 1):

The `Complete` property of the `Item` may be marked as internal in your code, you can change it to public to be able to use it in queries.

```
public class Item
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Boolean Complete { get; set; }
}
```

Also double check the where import if it uses the correct LINQ method.